# Aging a dataset

Tags: algorithm, math

For reasons I'd rather not go into, I need to filter a set of values to reduce jitter.  To that end, I need to be able to average a list of numbers, with the most recent having the greatest effect, and the least recent having the smallest effect.  I'm using a sample size of 10, but that could easily change at some point.

Are there any reasonably simple aging algorithms that I can apply here?

Comment: So, automated stock trading then ;)

Look at the wikipedia article on half life (the formula, not the game) and apply that to the values. That way, you'll get a time weighted average that should do what you need.

Comment: Voltages, actually, but a good guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Have a look at the [exponential smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing). Fairly simple, and might be sufficient for your needs. Basically recent observations are given relatively more weight than the older ones.
- Also (depending on the application) you may want to look at various reinforcement learning techniques, for example [Q-Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) or [TD-Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_difference_learning) or generally speaking any method involving the *discount*.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar in an embedded control application.

The simplest option that I came across was a 3/4 filter. This gets applied continuously over the entire data set:

```
current_value = (3*current_value + new_value)/4
```

I eventually decided to go with a 16-tap FIR filter instead:

[Overview](http://www.dsprelated.com/dspbooks/filters/Example_Zero_Phase_Filter_Design.html)
[FIR FAQ](http://www.dspguru.com/info/faqs/firfaq.htm)
[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response)

Answer (score 0):

Many weighted averaging algorithms could be used.

For example, for items I(n) for n = 1 to N in sequence (newest to oldest):

```
(SUM(I(n) * (N + 1 - n)) / SUM(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear from the question whether you're dealing with fixed-length
data or if data is continuously coming in. A nice physical model for the latter 
would be a low pass filter, using a capacitor and a resistor (R and C). Assuming
your data is equidistantly spaced in time (is it?), this leads to an update prescription

U_aged[n+1] = U_aged[n] + deltat/Tau (U_raw[n+1] - U_aged[n])

where Tau is the time constant of the filter. In the limit of zero deltat, this 
gives an exponential decay (old values will be reduced to 1/e of their value after
time Tau). In an implementation, you only need to keep a running weighted sum U_aged.

deltat would be 1 and Tau would specify the 'aging constant', the number of steps
it takes to reduce a sample's contribution to 1/e.